# Gettext ignoring translation

Tags: php, localization, gettext

```
putenv("LANG=fr_FR");
putenv('LC_ALL=fr_FR');
setlocale(LC_ALL, "fr_FR");
setlocale(LANG, "fr_FR");
setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, "fr_FR");
$domain = "fr_FR";
bindtextdomain($domain, "l10n");
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');
textdomain($domain);
```

With the folder structure:

```
l10n>FR>LC_MESSAGES>fr_FR.mo
l10n>FR>LC_MESSAGES>fr_FR.po
```

But no reaction, the strings stay in english no matter what I do.
Any what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why gettext doesn't work is quite a broad topic. Most often overlooked: does the locale `fr_FR` actually exist on your system? `$ locale -a`.

Comment: wow, indeed, will add it

Comment: it works !!!!! YAAY :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gettext doesn't translate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20482575/gettext-doesnt-translate)